# Can't add active state to my elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, function, class

So I tried to make a function similar to one from w3schools. The function needs to manage 2 things.
1. To add the ".active" class to a dot when the current page is called.
2.When the user clicks on dot to go to that page.

In my code, if I let some space when adding  a class through function 
Example(dots[sliderIndex].classList.add(" active");) now it works to click and go on that page but if I cut the space (dots[sliderIndex].classList.add("active");) now shows the active state but clicking on dots not working.
It confuses me so much...Please, guys if you can explain to me the logic behind and how to make this work.

```js
var sliderIndex = 0;

let next2 = document.querySelector(".next2");
let prev2 = document.querySelector(".prev2");

function showNews(n) {
  const slider = document.getElementsByClassName("news");
  const dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slider.length; i++) {
    slider[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  if (n < 0) {
    sliderIndex = slider.length - 1;
  }
  if (n > slider.length - 1) {
    sliderIndex = 0;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", " ");
  }
  slider[sliderIndex].style.display = "block";
  dots[sliderIndex].classList.add(" active");
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showNews((sliderIndex = n));
}

function incrementSlides2(n) {
  showNews((sliderIndex += n));
}
next2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  incrementSlides2(1);
});
prev2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  incrementSlides2(-1);
});

showNews(sliderIndex);
```

```css
#section-three .slideshow-container2 #dots {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
 
 justify-content: center;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .dot:hover,
#section-three .slideshow-container2 .dot.active {
  background: black;
}

.active{background:red}
```

```html
<section id="section-three">
    <div class="container slideshow-container2">
      <div class="news">
        <div class="news-content">
          <div class="buttons">
            <a class="btn company-btn" href="#">COMPANY NEWS</a>
            <a class="btn industry-btn" href="#">INDUSTRY NEWS</a>
          </div>
          <h1>OUR PEOPLE ARE OUT STONGEST ASSET </h1>
          
     
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="news news2">
        <div class="news2-content">
          <div class="buttons">
            <a class="btn company-btn" href="#">COMPANY NEWS</a>
            <a class="btn industry-btn" href="#">INDUSTRY NEWS</a>
          </div>
          <h1 class="media-room">MEDIA ROOM </h1>
          <div class="img">
            <img src="/Core/img/media.jpg" style="width:500px" alt="">
          </div>
         
          
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="dots">
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="prev2"></a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="next2"></a>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Just a note : in your snippet, remove the 'space' before `active` in `add(" active")` and `replace(" active")`. There is an `Uncaught InvalidCharacterError` otherwise

Comment: Without the extra space it just seems to work ... Clicking the dot is working ... The class `Name.replace` method seems to tolerate the "extra space". The `classList.add` don't so it just don't work. You also forgot to declare `i` in your for loops, though it shouldn't prevent your script from working.